# Can't Uninstall Angular CLI in Ubuntu - It says `up to date in 0.083s`

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, uninstallation

I can't uninstall Angular on Ubuntu 18.04 using this command

> npm uninstall -g angular-cli

or

> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

it says  :

> up to date in 0.083s

screenshot terminal:

[image]

please help

Answer (score 1):

You might need to update your node first, [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17905) is a known issue

Also

Uninstalls it from the current project

```
npm uninstall  @angular/cli
```

Uninstalls it globally

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```